# How to detect if a type is shared_ptr at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, shared-ptr, cereal

I want to get a templatized way of finding if a type is a shared_ptr and based on that I want to have a new specialization of a function.

Example main function is,

```
template <class T> inline
void CEREAL_LOAD_FUNCTION_NAME( RelaxedJSONInputArchive & ar,    NameValuePair<T> & t )
{
    std::cout << " CEREAL_LOAD_FUNCTION_NAME NameValuePair 1 " << std::endl;
     ar.setNextName( t.name );
     ar( t.value );
}
```

If t.value is shared_ptr then I want to have a different function specialization.
I have tried below,

```
template <class T> inline
typename std::enable_if<is_pointer<T>::value, void>::type
CEREAL_LOAD_FUNCTION_NAME( RelaxedJSONInputArchive & ar, NameValuePair<T> & t )
 {
    std::cout << " CEREAL_LOAD_FUNCTION_NAME NameValuePair 2 " << std::endl;
   ar.setNextName( t.name );
   ar( t.value );
  }
```

But it does not seem to work. These are part of c++11 cereal library. Which I am trying to customize.

Comment: Does `NameValuePair` have a member type telling you what `t.value` is?

Comment: NameValuePair is defined here.  https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/assets/doxygen/helpers_8hpp_source.html  .it has a    Type value member.

Comment: a "direct" overload should work, see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db3eae53e609bcfc

Answer (score 18):

the following may help:

```
template<typename T> struct is_shared_ptr : std::false_type {};
template<typename T> struct is_shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<T>> : std::true_type {};
```

then you can do the following to get the correct function:

```
template <class T> 
typename std::enable_if<is_shared_ptr<decltype(std::declval<T>().value)>::value, void>::type
func( T t )
{
    std::cout << "shared ptr" << std::endl;
}

template <class T> 
typename std::enable_if<!is_shared_ptr<decltype(std::declval<T>().value)>::value, void>::type
func( T t )
{
    std::cout << "non shared" << std::endl;
}
```

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a82bbbb42c3c2b6)

Comment: Will it work in my case.  Actually I have to get a new specialization of the function based on the type of a member called value.   If T::value is shared_ptr then I need new specialization.

Comment: This looks like the correct answer for the question.

Answer (score 13):

This is a basic case of [template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization). The following is a type trait that determines if a type T is a `shared_ptr` or not. It can be used the same way `std::is_pointer`, which you already use.

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct is_shared_ptr : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct is_shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<T>> : std::true_type {};
```

Demonstration :

```
static_assert(is_shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<int>>::value == true, "");
static_assert(is_shared_ptr<int>::value == false, "");
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer.

Comment: This definitely works and I also love the simplicity, but I don't understand why it works. Can anyone explain or point me to cpp reference or similar explaining this?

Comment: @IronAttorney The answer contains a link to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization which explains what partial specialization is. It basically says "there is a class template call `is_shared_ptr` with 1 type argument" and then says "when the template argument is a type of `std::shared_ptr<T>` use this version of the template instead".

Comment: Yeah sorry, I didn't give much detail to what was confusing me. So that is the right area, but to me it reads like you'll end up with a specialisation of `std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<int>>` as `T` is already a `std::shared_ptr<int>`. I'd have thought you'd need something more like `template<template<class T> class OUTER_T, class T> struct is_shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<T>>` or something similar (sorry, I've forgotten exacly how you have to write such a thing now, but hopefully that's close enough to get my meaning)

Comment: That confusion aside, you have helped me properly get what is happening here. The partial specialisation has a base class of `std::true_type`. That's cleared the fog alot there, thanks!

Comment: Nevermind sorry, the specialisation part all just clicked...

Answer (score 3):

If the **type provided is itself** a std::shared_ptr of some unknown type T, then the following use of SFINAE should help! Since all smart pointers provide a member type "`element_type`" we can specialize for `std::shared_ptr<T>`, `std::weak_ptr<T>`, and `std::unique_ptr<T>` as follows:

```
template<typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct is_smart_pointer
{
    enum { value = false };
};

template<typename T>
struct is_smart_pointer<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<T>::type, std::shared_ptr<typename T::element_type>>::value>::type>
{
    enum { value = true };
};

template<typename T>
struct is_smart_pointer<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<T>::type, std::unique_ptr<typename T::element_type>>::value>::type>
{
    enum { value = true };
};

template<typename T>
struct is_smart_pointer<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<T>::type, std::weak_ptr<typename T::element_type>>::value>::type>
{
    enum { value = true };
};
```