# How to check if a type is a smart pointer or a reference to a smart pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, typechecking

I am trying to implement a structure that checks at compile time if a given type is a smart pointer or a reference to a smart pointer.

I rewrote [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56225903/8401779) solution (that does not work for references):

```cpp
template<typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct IsSmartPointer : std::false_type {
};

template<typename T>
struct IsSmartPointer<T,
        typename std::enable_if<
                std::is_same<
                        typename std::decay_t<T>, std::unique_ptr<typename std::decay_t<T>::element_type>
                >::value
        >
> : std::true_type {
};

template<typename T>
struct IsSmartPointer<T,
        typename std::enable_if<
                std::is_same<
                        typename std::decay_t<T>, std::shared_ptr<typename std::decay_t<T>::element_type>
                >::value
        >
> : std::true_type {
};

template<typename T>
struct IsSmartPointer<T,
        typename std::enable_if<
                std::is_same<
                        typename std::decay_t<T>, std::weak_ptr<typename std::decay_t<T>::element_type>
                >::value
        >
> : std::true_type {
};
```

I feel this implementation is very close to the right solution. However, the code below prints zeros:

```cpp
std::cout << IsSmartPointer<int>::value                          << '\n'
          << IsSmartPointer<const std::shared_ptr<int> &>::value << '\n'
          << IsSmartPointer<std::shared_ptr<int> &>::value       << '\n'
          << IsSmartPointer<const std::shared_ptr<int>>::value   << '\n'
          << IsSmartPointer<std::shared_ptr<int>>::value
          << std::endl;
```

Could you try to find a mistake because I have run out of ideas?

Comment: Have u tried typeid().name; check syntax

Comment: @Mannoj I need to know the result at compile time.

Comment: When applied to an expression of polymorphic type, evaluation of a typeid expression may involve runtime overhead (a virtual table lookup), otherwise typeid expression is resolved at compile time.     https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

Comment: @Mannoj `typeid()` can appear in a constant expression, but the object it returns cannot be used at compile-time. None of its member functions are `constexpr`. Even if it was possible, the result of `.name()` is implementation-defined and need not be unique among types. Parsing it would also be much more complicated than using the SFINAE approach OP is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote `std::enable_if<...>`, when it should be `std::enable_if_t<...>` or `std::enable_if<...>::type`.

`std::enable_if<...>` is a distinct type that is never going to be `void`. So your partial specializations will never be used if the second template argument is defaulted to `void`.

---

Also note that you are forgetting custom deleters. `std::unique_ptr` has a second template argument for a custom deleter type that you will not catch if it isn't specified to the default.