# Differentiate between shared_ptr and normal type on compile time

Tags: c++, templates, shared-ptr

I try to create a templated class, which saves the template argument as a member variable (**msg_**).
Now the input of the class should allow normal types like `int` and `shared_ptr<int>`.

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo<T>() {};
 private:
  T msg_;
};
```

My problem is if the class gets initialized with `shared_ptr<int>`, the shared_ptr has to get initialized:

```
this->msg_ = std::make_shared<T*>();
```

I tried to solve it like this:

```
Foo<T>() {
    if (std::is_pointer<T>::value) {
      this->msg_ = std::make_shared<T*>();
    }
};
```

, but the problem is that is has to be solved on compile time. Otherwise I can not compile.

Do you know any patterns, which solve this issue?

Thank you! and
Best regards
Fabian

Comment: If `T` is `std::shared_ptr<int>`, `std::make_shared<T*>()` would return a `std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<int>*>`. Why is the default initialization not enough? (Also, what you're attempting is not initialization but assignment.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect if a type is shared\_ptr at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41853159/how-to-detect-if-a-type-is-shared-ptr-at-compile-time)

Comment: I'm using a callback method `std::function<void(T&)> user_callback`, which gets called with `this->user_callback(this->msg_)`. The problem I have is that the msg shared_ptr is a nullptr inside the function and thus my program crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have specialization

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {}
private:
    T msg_;
};
template <typename T>
class Foo<std::shared_ptr<T>>
{
public:
    Foo() : msg_(std::make_shared<T>()) {}
private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> msg_;
};
```

or create function to initialize (with overload)

```
template <typename> struct tag{};

template <typename T>
T foo_default_init(tag<T>) { return {}; }

template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> foo_default_init(tag<std::shared_ptr<T>>)
{
    return std::make_shared<T>();
}

template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() : msg_(foo_default_init(tag<T>{})){}
private:
    T msg_;
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Which C++ version are you using? 

The 2nd example fails to compile for me with C++11

Comment: Edited: Typo fixed.

Comment: I've just tested it and it solved my problem!

Thanks!